# How to get header ID from the HTML/DOM using react and typescript

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dom, markdown

I have an app that converts some markdown files to html using marked.js and displays the converted HTML to the web page. In the code snippet below I iterate over text nodes to grab all the raw text values that get displayed to store them in some index where a text value corresponds to a numeric id

```
    // iterate over file objects which contain raw markdown
    files.forEach(file => {
        // convert file's markdown string to html string using marked.js
        const htmlString = marked(file.markDown);
        const parser = new DOMParser();
        const doc = parser.parseFromString(htmlString, 'text/html');
        const walker = document.createTreeWalker(doc, NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT);
        // const walker = document.createTreeWalker(doc, NodeFilter.SHOW_ELEMENT);

        let currentNode = walker.currentNode;
        while (currentNode != null) {
            if (currentNode.textContent != null) {
                // index every HTML element's raw text value and assign it to an id
                searchIndexReference.push({ id: id++, text: currentNode.textContent });
                //console.log('currentNode');
                //console.log(currentNode);
            }
            const nextNode = walker.nextNode();
            if (nextNode != null) {
                currentNode = nextNode;
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
    });
```

I want to know **how I can grab the header id value and add it to the index as well, until the next header id is encountered**. That way the searchIndexReference will link text value entries to the header it was under.

Say we have some HTML below:

```
<h1 id="top-most-header">Top Most Header</h1>
<p>Here is some text 1</p>
<p>Here is some text 2</p>
<h2 id="some-other-section-header">Some Other Section Header</h1>
<p>Here is some text 3</p>
<p>Here is some text 4</p>
```

These entries would get appended to the searchIndexReference object like so. (Current header id value is stored until the next header is encountered)

```
{id: 1, headerId: 'top-most-header', text: 'Top Most Header'}
{id: 2, headerId: 'top-most-header', text: 'Here is some text 1'}
{id: 3, headerId: 'top-most-header', text: 'Here is some text 2'}
{id: 4, headerId: 'some-other-section-header', text: 'Some Other Section Header'}
{id: 5, headerId: 'some-other-section-header', text: 'Here is some text 3'}
{id: 6, headerId: 'some-other-section-header', text: 'Here is some text 4'}
```

This should work for nested elements as well too like ul, li, etc.

I know when I print out currentNode using

> const walker = document.createTreeWalker(doc, NodeFilter.SHOW_ELEMENT);

instead of NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT it shows the full HTML header element with the id, but I'm not sure where to go from there.

[printing out currentNode with SHOW_ELEMENT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UewMJ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check parent node and if it's a header then save the id

```
if(currentNode.parentNode.nodeName === 'H1') {
 headerId = currentNode.parentNode.id
}
```

Comment: the .id property does not exist on parentNode. i am able to get the code working by using currentNode.parentElement instead, but it skips over entries that contain 'href' or '<em>'